# iphone app development screen size issue

Tags: ios, iphone, screen, resolution

Now iPhone 6 has come out, and now there are 4 screen sizes.

Is there any way to optimise all these screen in one code base?

Am I have to change all my existing apps *(without using storyboard & nib, all UI coded programmatically)* to fit in these screen?

The layout I hardcoded by pixel. e.g.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 65)];
```

How to effectively solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use self.view.frame.size. It gets the width and height of the screen and you can use it.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

hope this helps :)